# How to use MongodbJobStore (via file quartz.properties) connect to mongodb in project java webapplication?

Tags: java, mongodb, quartz-scheduler

I've issuse with configure file quartz.properties connect to mongodb.
this is my file quartz.properties

```
#specify the jobstore used
org.quartz.jobStore.class=com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri=mongodb://localhost:27017
#The datasource for the jobstore that is to be used
org.quartz.jobStore.dbName=myds
org.quartz.jobStore.addresses=host1,host2
#quartz table prefixes in the database
org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=quartz_
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4
```

Can anyone recommend either a way to back Quartz with MongoDB use quartz.properties, or a simple alternative to Quartz?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  What's not working?  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I'm try to use quartz.properties connect to db (mongodb), but i don't know how can I do it? :(... i had followed https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method for get scheduler with/without properties

```
public Scheduler getScheduler(Properties properties) {
    SchedulerFactory factory;

    if (!properties.isEmpty()) {
        // with properties
        factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    } else {
        // without properties
        factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    }

    return factory.getScheduler();
}
```

And this method for load properties file

```
public Scheduler load() throws SchedulerException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        // file 'quartz.properties' in the 'src/main/resources/config' (Maven project structure)
        properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/my-quartz.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // process the exception, maybe load default properties
    }

    return getScheduler(properties);
}
```

You can put properties file into 'src/main/resources/config' folder,

or set $JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.quartz.properties=/config/my-quartz.properties

Also you can load properties with Spring

```
@Component
public class SchedulerLoader {
    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.class}")
    private String quartzJobStoreClass;

    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri}")
    private String quartzJobStoreMongoUri;

    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.dbName}")
    private String quartzJobStoreDbName;

    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix}")
    private String quartzJobStoreCollectionPrefix;

    @Value("${org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount}")
    private String quartzThreadPoolThreadCount;

    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.addresses}")
    private String quartzJobStoreAddresses;

    public Scheduler load() throws SchedulerException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.class", quartzJobStoreClass);
            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri", quartzJobStoreMongoUri);
            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.dbName", quartzJobStoreDbName);

            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix", quartzJobStoreCollectionPrefix);
            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", quartzThreadPoolThreadCount);
            properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.addresses", quartzJobStoreAddresses);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // process the exception, maybe load default properties
        }

        return getScheduler(properties);
    }
    ...
```

with Spring config

```
<beans ...>
    ...
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/*.properties"/>
    ...
```

There are properties file

```
# Use the MongoDB store
org.quartz.jobStore.class=com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore

# MongoDB URI (optional if 'org.quartz.jobStore.addresses' is set)
org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri=mongodb://localhost:27020

# comma separated list of mongodb hosts/replica set seeds (optional if 'org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri' is set)
org.quartz.jobStore.addresses=host1,host2

# database name
org.quartz.jobStore.dbName=quartz

# Will be used to create collections like mycol_jobs, mycol_triggers, mycol_calendars, mycol_locks
org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=mycol

# thread count setting is ignored by the MongoDB store but Quartz requries it
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
```

Also you should add Maven dependency (check https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb for details)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.novemberain</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
```